# Unable to share git repo with Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I have an existing local repository undeg Git. Now I want to push it to Bitbucket.

If I just set remote

```
git remote add bitbucket <https://URL>
```

it say repository doesn't exist.

If I first create repository from Bitbucket page, then

```
>git push --all bitbucket
To https://URL
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://URL'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And if I do

```
>git pull bitbucket master
From https://URL
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Looks like deadend.

What else can be done?

I don't want to cheat with cloning empty repository first and then populating it with files. I want to push existing repo to Bitbucket.

Comment: Ad `-f` to the `git push` command (only once)

Comment: That's easy, thanks